# C# - Lists inside lists

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I need some help.

I'm trying to store information inside of lists.

For example, the user types in number, age, address and hair color...

And I want to make lists inside of lists to store the information, like this:

```
[0] Number

----[0] Age

----------[0] Address

----------[1] Adrress

--------------[0] Hair Color
```

If there is a better way to do this please help me!
With lists inside of list I will be very confused, but if it is the better solution, I've no problem.

Comment: Why not make a class? Then you can have a list of classes that contain stuff.

Comment: Lists are not mean to hold structured data like your example.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault And can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: @xbonez So what is the best?

Comment: You can hardly find more basic stuff than classes; start by learning C# (or any OO language) and you'll see how.. You can find a bunch of of online tutorials and resources

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I need help. I trying to learn, if you help me I would be very happy.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an online classroom, if you want to learn there's plenty of resources for that; read books, find online tutorials, follow a course.. With programming you need to try stuff by yourself and not get spoon-fed, else you'll never be able to achieve anything.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I also wanted to know if there was other way to do what I want, you told me about list of classes, I will look for that, thanks. Ps: I'm following computer science, I'm reading a huge book about Java and I learn C# from that. And I also keep trying to improve doing apps for android and pc.

Comment: @NunoBatalha: You run any object oriented language- java,c# etc, you gotta face these objects. What David has answered is the best possible solution. Stackoverflow community tries to help you out with specific problems.

Comment: @Sangram Yes I know he is right. But I can also learn when someone help me, no?

Comment: Does your schema mean that the same person has different colour hair depending upon which address they are using?

Comment: @GarryVass Yes :P It was just an exemple. I've used lists inside classes. It's resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Storing logically-grouped data as arrays of primitive values isn't really the way to go with this.  Instead, [replace the array with an object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceArrayWithObject.html) and just store the list of objects.  In your example, the object could be as simple as:

```
class Person
{
    public int Number { get; set; } // it's not clear what this value means
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string HairColor { get; set; }
}
```

You can add more properties, logic, validation, strongly-typed enumerations (for things like `HairColor`), etc. to this object.  Maintaining a collection of this is easy:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
```

One of the key benefits you'd immediately notice with this approach is that the structure of the `Person` can change without having to change any of the collections which store `Person`s.  You can add/alter/remove properties and it's still just a `List<Person>`.  You'd only have to change code which uses the components that you're changing.

Another key benefit is that you can encapsulate all of the logic which defines a `Person` within this class, so other code doesn't need to worry about it.  So instead of having to re-write the same validation logic for example (always making sure `Age` is a valid positive number, things like that), you can just write it on the object and it's applied everywhere.  As Eric Raymond once said, "Smart data structures and dumb code work a lot better than the other way around."

Answer (score 4):

You need a class structure take a look at this example:

```
public enum AddressType{
     Work,
     Home,
     Other
}

class Address{
    public AddressType AddressType{get;set;}
    public AddressLine1 {get;set;}
    public AddressLine2 {get;set;}
    public string City{get;set;}
    public string State{get;set;}
}

class User
{
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string HairColor{get;set;}
    public List<Address> AddressList{get;set;}
    public User(){
         AddressList = new List<Address>();
    }
}

class UserList:List<User>{
}
```

Then you can make use of this code like this:

```
var users = new UserList();
var usr = new User{FirstName = "Steve", LastName="Ruben", Age = 32, HairColor = "Brown"};
usr.AddressList.Add(new AddressList{AddressLine1 = "Address ln 1", AddressLine2 = "Address ln 2", City = "Some Place", State = "WI", AddressType = AddressType.Home});
users.Add(usr);
```